# Notation for the space of functions with $L^2$ derivative, but may themselves not be $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the space of functions $$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$ such that $$f(0) = 0$$ and $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(x)^2 dx < \infty$$.

Does this sort of space have a common notation or name?

Note that this is not the same space as $L^2_1$, since I do not require the functions themselves to be $L^2$. For example the function $$f(x) = \tanh(x)$$ is not $L^2$ but is in the above space.

Comment: Do you want $f$ to be continuous? What is $f’$?

Comment: You could define this space to be the completion of the smooth functions with compact support such that $f(0) = 0$ under the norm given by $|f|^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(x)^2 dx$

Comment: I don't know any notation for such a space. Maybe $\overline{\mathcal D _0(\mathbb R)}^{H^1}$ would do the job, where $\mathcal D _0 = \mathcal D \cap  \{ f(0 ) =0 \}$ is not conventional but cannot lead to confusion.